# Universal iOS app INCOMPATIBLE on iPad Air 2 in TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile, testflight

**I believe this is a TestFlight bug in that iPad Air 2 devices aren't being recognised, see updates below**

One of our apps is incompatible through TestFlight on iPad Air 2 and as such we are unable to download it. It is however very similar to another app which is absolutely fine.

1. A little background on the development of our apps. The first app that we *are* having trouble with started development before the iPad Air 2 was released. The second app was started after the iPad Air 2 was released and is fine.
2. One of the iPad Air 2 devices is included in the provisioning profile and the other isn't.
3. Both iPad Air 2 devices can install the second app but not the first.
4. The *incompatible* app is installable and works fine on the original iPad Air.
5. Each app has its own provisioning profile and they are all up to date, each using our full quota of 100 devices. As said before, one of the iPad Air 2 devices is included in the 100 and the other isn't.
6. I am using Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a)
7. I am distributing my app through TestFlight
8. I have checked the binary and it **is** built for both architectures

   ```
   file My\ Project
   My\ Project: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
   My\ Project (for architecture armv7):   Mach-O executable arm
   My\ Project (for architecture arm64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable
   ```
9. I am using CocoaPods.

Here is my Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, "7.1"

target "My Project" do

pod 'PromiseKit'
pod 'PureLayout'
pod 'CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout'
pod 'RNTimer'
pod 'FXBlurView'
pod 'ionicons'
pod 'FormatterKit'
pod 'HMSegmentedControl', '~> 1.3.0'
pod 'DACircularProgress'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'NSMutableURLRequest-BasicAuth'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'FCModel'
pod 'FlurrySDK'

end
```

I have included two screenshots below, and if there is any more information you would require in order to help answer this question please do comment below. I am not sure what else I need to or what I should check.

These are my project's architectures.

[image: Project Architectures]

[image: App OK]

[image: Incompatible warning]

### Update 1

The issue appears to be with TestFlight (although this is not confirmed) as sometime incremental builds are stuck on processing and when I receive the *invite to test* email, it shows an old build number.

### Update 2

I have incremented not only the **build** number but the **version** number too.

I have created a new **Ah Doc and App Store** Certificate and regenerated my **provisioning profiles** yet this hasn't helped as far as I can tell.

If I could draw your attention to the two iPad screenshots. The first (showing our app that *does* work and the second that shows the app that *doesn't* work. Under the compatibility, in our app that *does* work, **Requires iOS 7.0 or later. Compatible with iPod touch, iPhone, and iPad.** In our app that *doesn't* work, the compatibility reads **Requires iOS 7.1 or later. Compatible with iPod touch, iPhone, iPad 2 Wi-Fi, ...**

Also, I have updated the iPad landscape launch images as they were showing as missing however that too still hasn't solved the issue.

I do believe that it is an issue with TestFlight.

### Update 3

Below is a screenshot taken this morning (26 Jan 2015) that depicts an ongoing issue with TestFlight (I think this could be related).

[image: TestFlight Processing Issue]

As you can see, on multiple occasions the app's status was stuck on Processing, hence the reason for a few incremental build number changes (as suggested in another SO question). No code was changed between these builds.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. Architectures and Valid architectures are set to arm64 armv7 armv7s, but Testflight says thay my app is not conpatible with iPad Air 2.

Comment: I have submitted a ticket with ITS, subject to NDA I will update if I receive any more info. Do come back here and update if you *too* find any more information.

Comment: I think it's a Apple Testflight bug, because I've try download the app from former Testflight platform, and there was no problem on install it in an iPad Air 2.

Comment: Hi Mike, have you solved this incompatibility problem with iPad Air 2? I can't still install an app on an iPad Air 2 through TestFlight.

Comment: @RFG I am no longer with the company that was trying to solve this so I am not sure to be honest. Sorry, I wish I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CocoaPods? What architectures have you set in your project file?
You should set "Valid architectures" for project and target to: armv7, armv7s and arm64.
[image]

Comment: Both are using **Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)** and the Valid Architectures are **arm64, armv7, armv7s**

Comment: Have you tried install this app on iPad Air 2 without TestFlight?

Comment: Yes I have and it says **Finished running my_project on Mike's iPad** but it doesn't.